# How to properly draw preview thumbnail in Unity editor window?

Tags: unity-game-engine

### Background

I am currently building a custom Unity editor plugin that allows users to modify selected images.

The plugin features a small preview area that the user can look at before exporting the resulting image to disk.

```
MyCustomEditorPlugin : EditorWindow
{
    Texture2D selected_texture;

    ...

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.DrawTexture(some_rect, selected_texture);
    }
}
```

### Problem

Unfortunately, directly drawing the selected image on each call of `OnGUI` causes major lag.

Does anyone know of any best practices when drawing preview images on custom Unity editor windows (aka ways of solving this problem)?

Comment: Could maybe link the preview to a button prompt. That way it only get called once when told to do so. Otherwise have a boolean it checks against to see if any changes were made and only draw the texture if true, then set it to false until more changes are made.

Comment: @TimHunter `Otherwise have a boolean it checks against to see if any changes were made and only draw the texture if true, then set it to false until more changes are made. ` What do you mean by this? I didn't know you could conditionally redraw only portions of area with `OnGUI`. As a total beginner in Unity, could you provide some sample code?

Comment: @AlanSTACK You can't conditionally redraw in OnGui, its the Immediate Gui system (IMGui) and must be redrawn every frame.

Comment: @AlanSTACK could you add the full code? I tested a simple image and I don't have any lag .. it probably depends very much on the texture resolution etc

Comment: I just tested it with an image `13586*7778 pixels` and maximum texture import settings and couldn't confirm any lag ...  you might as well want to try if `EditorGUI.ObjectField(some_rect, selected_texture, typeof(Texture2D));` reduces the lag for you

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for your response. Could you please also upload your computer specifications? I will try to look deeper into the problem to find any other possible explanations.

Comment: @AlanSTACK actually really nothing special it's a Laptop: Windows10, 16G RAM, Intel Core i7-6700HQ (2.6GHz), NVidia GeForce 960M

Comment: @derHugo Your laptop literally has better specs than my desktop by a considerable margin.

Comment: @AlanSTACK Oh, I'm sorry for that. Well it's a Gaming-Laptop made for doing Unity stuff but I really didn't expect it to run out a Desktop in these days.

Comment: I've drawn dozens of textures in an inspector and noticed no lag, although its probably better to keep the texture size down (to avoid aliasing issues but also to gain some performance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, so it skips the draw step until it gets set to true by something else:

```
MyCustomEditorPlugin : EditorWindow
{
    Texture2D selected_texture;

    bool changesMade = false;

    ...

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        if(changesMade) {
          GUI.DrawTexture(some_rect, selected_texture);
        }
    }
}
```

Other idea using a counter to limit the number of draw calls:

```
MyCustomEditorPlugin : EditorWindow
{
    Texture2D selected_texture;

    int functionCount = 0;

    ...

    public void OnGUI()
    {
        if(functionCount > 20) {
          GUI.DrawTexture(some_rect, selected_texture);
          functionCount = 0;
        }
        functionCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that just now and instead of using a previously drawn image. It just doesn't draw the image at all (i.e. some frames, that specific section of the editor window is just blank). This is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, dug into the documentation and discovered my initial idea for it was naive. Could not find a way to have it call the image draw once and freeze it, so I think you have two other options you can look into. Compress the data it's trying to draw so it has less to run through or see if you can use threading to make the work it does more efficient.

Comment: @AlanSTACK Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a way to have it retain information on the draw calls that I could find. Another approach that might help is if you throttle the number of function calls like I edited into my answer above. You would have to figure out a good rate for this so that it doesn't cause annoying flickering of the image though...

Comment: Your throttling method doesn't work man. If you throttle the draw calls, the throttled frames don't just retain their old visuals. They become straight up blank.

Comment: @TimHunter `OnGUI` is called multiple times per "frame" or better said for various events like mouse movement, clicks, editor repaints etc. To draw the texture only sometimes will always result in "blinking" and is probably not what the OP is after.

Comment: @AlanSTACK Hmm, gotcha. How about making a copy of the image and changing the resolution of the copy then use that to draw to the GUI preview? So long as the updates to the copy isn't called every frame, say every time an edit is made instead, it should work faster I think... It won't be representative of the quality of the actual result, but it should reduce the cost of the draw image calls.